# Richtext editor for PHP - MySQL web application

Tags: php, editor, richtext

I have a PHP web application inside where i need to have a rich text editor(with basic formating options) for my users to enter data in to the portal.

Can any one tell me how to do this ? Will there be any change in the database saving part since i am saving data in a mysql DB

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCKeditor is pretty good and is painlessly easy to use. Some simple javascript calls at page load and it'll magically replace textareas with RTEs. plus it runs well on browsers going   all the way back to IE5.5. There should be no impact on your database assuming you are already prepared to cope with HTML coming in from your textareas...

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe RTE(rich text editor) from yahoo user interface library?

[Yahoo editor.](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)

Which I think might have some benefits:

- Hosting (fast, optimized) from yahoo

Answer (score 2):

Spaw editor don't update for some reason, so I switched to [the Cute Editor for PHP](http://phphtmledit.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You should give a go to [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/).

You can also take a look at [these](http://blog.webdistortion.com/2008/03/09/9-of-the-best-rich-text-editors-reviewed/).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/), it's easy to [integrate with PHP](http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/PHP)...

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different options, the most prevalent being [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and[FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/).  I recommend [shopping around](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/WebEditors) a little bit for one you like, but they should all submit valid html in forms, etc.  The biggest difference may be in the way you [validate input](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html) to protect against XSS attacks (you need to allow 'safe html' in form submissions; [this](http://htmlpurifier.org/) looks promising).

Answer (score 1):

i like [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Answer (score 1):

To use any of the RTF style editors you have to set the fields in which you are going to store text to be of data type LongText.

Both TinyMCE and FCKEditor are good and both will store text formatting information as HTML Tags.

In both cases inserting graphics and/or Flash will require you to first upload the content to using their interface and then insert it.

We have observer that TinyMCE seems to be faster to load compared to FCKEditor on our systems.

Answer (score 1):

I have reviewed many of these systems and find, like many of the posters above, that FCKEditor and TinyMCE are the best.  I go with FCK though because it has bult-in file/image upload support - you have to pay for module to achieve this on TinyMCE.

Comment: FCKEditor has a commercial licence or an open source personal and educational use licence, depending on your requirements.
http://www.fckeditor.net/license

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried but [MarkitUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) appears great. It was built on the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using the **SPAW** editor for a few years now, which you handle and code via PHP instead of JavaScript (so its a server-side coding perspective instead of client-side).

We have found it to be **extremely extensible and customizable**.

If you want to have a look, here is the link:
http://www.spaweditor.com/

Answer (score 1):

[**Nicedit**](http://nicedit.com/) is an easy-to-use and lightweight (~25KB) WYSIWYG editor for Javascript.

You can customize the style and the buttons you want to appear in the toolbar.

You can also extend it, saving data with AJAX, generate valid XHTML, create multiple editors, upload images, BBCode, and more...

I use it with jQuery and I'm very satisfied with the results

And it's open source :) with a MIT License